# csv file requires to open and save again in order to display data.

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am exporting csv file from server and using php script to fetch data from the csv and show on the webpage.

Now it's all working good.

But problem is I always have to open the exported csv file first and copy paste the date to another csv file.

It is not fetching any data from the exported file straight away.

It's weird, as I said when I copy the data and provide the same name to the csv file, so everything is same, It works.

Why is like that.

php function(Although I don't think there is any problem with that)

```
    public function import(){


    $fp = fopen(DATA_PATH.'/testfile.csv', 'r');

    // get the first (header) line
    $header = fgetcsv($fp);

    // get the rest of the rows
    $data = array();
    while ($row = fgetcsv($fp)) {
      $arr = array();
      foreach ($header as $i => $col)
        $arr[$col] = $row[$i];
      $data[] = $arr;
    }



    $all = $data; 
    $soldVal=array();
    foreach ($all as $key=>$value){
        $sold = $value["total_qty_ordered"];
        array_push($soldVal, $sold);
    }

    print_R($soldVal);
    //echo '<br/>';
    $totalSeats = intval('1000');
    $prodTotal = intval(array_sum($soldVal));
    $totalLeft = $totalSeats-$prodTotal;

    return 
     'Products Sold '.$prodTotal;
            //.' Seats Left '.$totalLeft;

}
```

Comment: would opening in `'r+'` mode help ?

Comment: Nothing at all to do with PHPExcel, but are you sure your original file really is a csv file?